# IntelliJ Delete Groovy Console When close

Tags: java, intellij-idea, groovy-console

Everytime I want to run some simple Java/Groovy code in the Groovy Console, it saves a groovy file at my IntelliJ AppData directory (C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\IdeaIC2020.3\consoles\groovy\groovy_console_5.groovy):

[image]

There is a easy way to delete this file when close the Groovy Console window?

Answer (score 0):

This behavior is by design and there is no way to change it. Many users complained that the code they written in the console can be lost, so it was changed to the scratch files type view.

You can still select and delete the older files manually.

Comment: How can I open an old groovy console?

Comment: You can't, sorry.